# indexOf null exception

Tags: java, arrays, list, hyperlink

```
public int indexOf(X item)
{
    Node <X> current = head;
    int c = 0;
    if (current.getValue().equals(item))
    {
        return c;
    }
    while (current != null)
    {
        current = current.getLink();
        c++;
        if (current.getValue().equals(item))
        {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

.

```
@Test
public void testIndexOf()
{
    LList<String> b = new LList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        b.add("str" + i);

    assertEquals(19, b.indexOf("str0"));
    assertEquals(0, b.indexOf("str19"));
    assertEquals(-1, b.indexOf("not found"));
}
```

For some reason the last assertion is bringing up an error as Nullpointer exception. but i made it so when it does reach null to return -1, which is what i was trying to return in the third assertion in the test, what am i missing here?

Comment: Did you look at the line number in the exception?  What part of the stack trace did you find confusing (assuming you did, otherwise you wouldn't be posting here)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
while (current != null)
{
    current = current.getLink();
```

You ensure that `current` is not `null` . . . but then you immediately change `current` in a way that makes it possible for it to be `null` again. And you'll reach that case whenever `item` is not present in your linked-list.

You can fix this by rearranging the code a bit:

```
public int indexOf(X item)
{
    Node <X> current = head;
    int c = 0;
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.getValue().equals(item))
        {
            return c;
        }
        current = current.getLink();
        c++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: yeah that worked, but how is that any different from what i wrote, i am still not understanding. i did while current isnt null move to the next link, and if that isnt null either do the same, until you reach item. or throw -1 if its not there

Comment: You test if `current` is non-null; then, you set `current` to `current.getLink()`, which may be null; then, you try to call `current.getValue()` -- but you can't do that if `current` is null. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (current != null)
{
    current = current.getLink();
    c++;
    if (current.getValue().equals(item))
    {
        return c;
    }
}
return -1;
```

You are advancing to the next link after your null check.  `current.getLink` is returning null.